# Android UI testing with mocked dependencies

Tags: android, mockito, ui-testing, android-instrumentation

I have an activity in which I provide a button. Clicking on the button invokes a method in a data provider class and based on the return value of the method I make UI changes. Now I want to write an instrumented test where I perform `click()` in the button but avoid actually calling the method in the data provider class. Instead I want to return a desired value from the method and then check if the UI was modified accordingly.

**MyActivity**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                boolean result = dataProvider.getResult();
                if(result) {
                   mSuccessTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Here, on button click, a call is made to `DataProvider#getResult` and the result from this method is stored in `result`. If the result is `true` a TextView `mSuccessTextView`, previously `GONE`, is now made `VISIBLE`.
The problem here is `DataProvider#getResult` deals with a lot of external components that would make testing impossible. So what I want to do is use a mocked instance of `DataProvider` so that I can get `getResult` to return a desired value and then check the visibility of `mSuccessTextView`. **This is what I tried :**

**MyActivityTest.java**

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MyActivityTest {

    private DataProvider mDataProvider;

    @Rule
    public IntentsTestRule<MyActivity> mIntentRule =
            new IntentsTestRule<>(MyClientActivity.class);

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mDataProvider = mock(DataProvider.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testResultSuccess() {
        boolean result = true;
        when(mDataProvider.getResult()).thenReturn(result);
        onView(withId(R.id.action_button)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.success_text_view)).check((ViewAssertion) isDisplayed());
    }
}
```

Doing the above generates the following error :

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:
Mockito cannot mock this class: class com.domain.myapp.DataProvider.

Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes.
If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.

Underlying exception : java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot define class using reflection
.
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot define class using reflection
.
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This JVM's version string does not seem to be valid: 0
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you could mock `DataProvider`, it would not help you because you are not injecting its instance into `MyClientActivity` during your test. Reasons for not able to mock `DataProvider` are unknown, pls provide the class.

Comment: Why can I not mock `DataProvider `? Talking irrespective of the contents of the class, I am able to mock it during unit testing since it is a public and non-final class. Why am I not able to mock it during instrumentation testing ?